# How to pop array values that are before a specific date in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

So i am working with an api for a video game that returns guild member exp objects:

```
"expHistory": {
                "2020-11-26": 84825,
                "2020-11-25": 87219,
                "2020-11-24": 44447,
                "2020-11-23": 14849,
                "2020-11-22": 57379,
                "2020-11-21": 32364,
                "2020-11-20": 42295
            }
```

I need to determine the total value of all the guild exp for each member, however i want to only include exp that was earned **after** monday. I had a really terrible system that *worked* but often broke due to a various number of things. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Monday are you referring to?

Comment: well whichever monday is present in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries), [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to compute the total points for the desired date range.

We just need to enter the correct date threshold:

```js
let obj = { 
    "expHistory": {
        "2020-11-26": 84825,
        "2020-11-25": 87219,
        "2020-11-24": 44447,
        "2020-11-23": 14849,
        "2020-11-22": 57379,
        "2020-11-21": 32364,
        "2020-11-20": 42295
    }
}
            
function getTotal(thresholdDate, expHistory) {
    let result = Object.entries(expHistory)
        .filter(([date, points]) => date > thresholdDate)
        .reduce((total, [date, points]) => total + points, 0);
    return result;
}
 
const thresholdDate = "2020-11-20";
console.log(`Total (from ${thresholdDate}):`, getTotal(thresholdDate, obj.expHistory));
```